# Title in header in UITableView not shown?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I m using this code for setting title and background color with UITableView but title is not shown?

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return @"Contents";
}

- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)] autorelease];
    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:headerView];

    return headerView;
}
```

Please Help...

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, once you return something for `viewForHeaderInSection` the value returned in `titleForHeaderInSection` is no longer used.  In `viewForHeaderInSection` add a UILabel as a subview to `headerView` and set the text to `@"Contents"`

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code to this and ckeck only you have to implement viewForHeaderInSection method :

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    NSString *cellValue = @"";
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)] ;
    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor]];

    UILabel *lblContent = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, headerView.frame.size.width,  headerView.frame.size.height)];
    cellValue = [[arrSections objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"CategoryName"];
    lblContent.text = cellValue;
    [headerView addSubview:lblContent];
    return headerView;
}
```